# Best practice: deploying depencencies on Linux

Tags: linux, dependencies, shared-libraries

What is the best practice for deploying dependencies on Linux when shipping an own application?

Some SO posts recommend to include all dependencies in the package (utilizing LD_LIBRARY_PATH), other posts recommend to only ship the binary and use the "dependency" feature of the DEB/RPM packages instead. I tried to use the second approach, but immediately ran into the problem that one dependency (libicu52) doesn't seem to be available in certain Linux distributions yet. For example, in my OpenSuse test installation only "libicu51" is available in the package manager.

I initially thought that the whole idea of the packaging system is to avoid duplicate SO files in the system. But does it really work (see above), or should I rather ship all dependencies with my app, to make sure that it runs on all distributions?

Answer (score 1):

For custom application, which "does not care" about distribution-specific packaging, versioning, it's upgrades, etc,. I would recommend to redistribute dependencies manually.

You can use `RPATH` linker option, by it's setting value to `$ORIGIN` you will tell linker to search libraries in directory, relative to that binary file, without need to pre-set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before execution:

```
  gcc -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib'
```

Example taken from [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).